# Split Rx Observable into multiple streams and process individually

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java, rxjs

Here is a picture of what I am attempting to accomplish.

--a-b-c-a--bbb--a

split into

--a-----a-------a   --> a stream

----b------bbb---   --> b stream

------c----------   --> c stream

Then, be able to

```
a.subscribe()
b.subscribe()
c.subscribe()
```

So far, everything I have found has split the stream using a groupBy(), but then collapsed everything back into a single stream and process them all in the same function. What I want to do is process each derived stream in a different way.

The way I'm doing it right now is doing a bunch of filters. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't have to collapse `Observables` from `groupBy`. You can instead subscribe to them.

Something like this:

```
String[] inputs= {"a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a"};

Action1<String> a = s -> System.out.print("-a-");

Action1<String> b = s -> System.out.print("-b-");

Action1<String> c = s -> System.out.print("-c-");

Observable
    .from(inputs)
    .groupBy(s -> s)
    .subscribe((g) -> {
        if ("a".equals(g.getKey())) {
            g.subscribe(a);
        }

        if ("b".equals(g.getKey())) {
            g.subscribe(b);
        }

        if ("c".equals(g.getKey())) {
            g.subscribe(c);
        }
    });
```

If statements look kinda ugly but at least you can handle each stream separately. Maybe there is a way of avoiding them.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to avoid having those ifs possibly. However, if it works out, then it'll look a bit cleaner since its all in one place, rather than doing filters on the original stream. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! I'll update my answer if I figure out how to get rid of `if` statements.

Comment: You could use a `Dictionary<groupKey,action>`, and your group `subscribe` method would have to resolve the action from the dictionary and call it.

Comment: Something like `Dictionary<String, Action1<String>> handlers = new Hashtable<>(); handlers.put("a", s -> System.out.println("-a-"));....` and `.subscribe((g) -> { Action1<String> action = handlers.get(g.getKey()); g.subscribe(action); });`

Comment: Brandon Bill, I had to reread your question to figure out that you were originally using `filter`. Out of curiosity, what makes you prefer this `groupBy` solution to the `filter` one? To me `filter` seems simpler, easier to understand, probably better performing. What advantages do you see in `groupBy`?

Comment: I noticed some interesting things while debugging (note this is using Rx JS), where once a "group" had been associated with a handler, another instance of an element from the group would not go through the big subscribe function shown above. Instead it would forward directly to the Action that the group was subscribed to. Whereas, with a filter the comparisons get made for every single value of the source observable. Therefore, with N splits, a possible N comparisons will be made for every element. With groups, comparisons are only made when a new group is found.

Answer (score 43):

Easy as pie, just use `filter`

An example in scala

```scala
import rx.lang.scala.Observable

val o: Observable[String] = Observable.just("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a")
val hotO: Observable[String] = o.share
val aSource: Observable[String] = hotO.filter(x ⇒ x == "a")
val bSource: Observable[String] = hotO.filter(x ⇒ x == "b")
val cSource: Observable[String] = hotO.filter(x ⇒ x == "c")

aSource.subscribe(o ⇒ println("A: " + o), println, () ⇒ println("A Completed"))

bSource.subscribe(o ⇒ println("B: " + o), println, () ⇒ println("B Completed"))

cSource.subscribe(o ⇒ println("C: " + o), println, () ⇒ println("C Completed"))
```

You just need to make sure that the source observable is hot. The easiest way is to `share` it.

Comment: What if you want or initial observable to be cold?

Comment: @double_squeeze just use `publish` instead of `share` and invoke `connect` when all of subsribers are subscribed.

Comment: There is no point in making it hot using `share`. Provided code actually subscribes three times - for each subscriber, same as it would without `share`. The right way to do it is described in Krzysztof Skyrzynecki's comment: use `publish` instead of `share` and invoke `connect` when all of subsribers are subscribed.

Comment: I do agree that the `publish`+`connect` method is cleaner and I would use it whenever feasible (but sometimes, you just don't know the subscribers in advance and don't care that you miss some items). However, I don't think your statement about three subscriptions to the original cold `o` is correct. If you can prove otherwise, please `share()` :) your proof with us.

Answer (score 1):

I have been thinking about this and Tomas solution is OK, but the issue is that it converts the stream to a hot observable.

You can use `share` in combination with `defer` in order to get a cold observable with other streams.

For example (Java):

```java
var originalObservable = ...; // some source
var coldObservable = Observable.defer(() -> {
    var shared - originalObservable.share();
    var aSource = shared.filter(x -> x.equals("a"));
    var bSource = shared.filter(x -> x.equals("b"));
    var cSource = shared.filter(x -> x.equals("c"));
    // some logic for sources
    return shared;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In RxJava there is a special version of [publish operator](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#publish-rx.functions.Func1-) that takes a function.

```
ObservableTransformer {
  it.publish { shared ->
    Observable.merge(
        shared.ofType(x).compose(transformerherex),
        shared.ofType(y).compose(transformerherey)
    )
  }
}
```

This splits the event stream by type. Then you can process them separately by composing with different transformers. All of them share single subscription.